# How can I plot sequence segmentation results in a color plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, video-processing

I am new to this field of sequence segmentation. What I want to do is something like this:
Given a temporal sequence (i.e. video), I assign a label to each 1 second of this video along time axis. I can have two list:

```
(1)  GroundTruth_List = ['sit', 'sit', 'sit', 'order_coco', 'order_coco', 'drink_coco']
(2)  Predicted_List = ['sit', 'sit', 'sit', 'order_coco', 'order_coco', 'drink_milk']
```

I hope to roughly visualize how many wrong predictions were made for this video.
After searching online, I find maybe matplotlib might be the correct direction.
Can someone provide some exemplary code on how to visualize the above two lists? For example, two horizontal lines representing the two list, if the segment class is 'sit', we plot it as blue color, but for other classes,  we plot the line as a different color automatically.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code request service. We help with fixing (debugging) and improving code, not writing code from scratch. I recommend trying this yourself and updating the question with an actual issue. As is, your question is at risk of being closed.